# Is it bad Python style to return empty iterators rather than None?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Opinions seem to be mixed on this -- is there a Pythonic "right way" to do this?

Comment: "Right way" given what context?

Comment: An example would be returning results from a REST query.

Answer (score 7):

I think empty iterator is better because iterating over nothing is faster then first checking if returned value is not None and then iterate over or not.

```
for x in function():
    do_something()

value = function()
if value is not None:
    for x in value:
        do_something()
```

Just look at this.

Also normally you dont initialize iter attributes with None, but with empty iter object.

```
self.list_of_users = []
```

not

```
self.list_of_users = None
```

Comment: _"iterating over nothing is faster"_ `[citation-needed]`. Yes, it's _terser,_ but without some `timeit` results, I'm unconvinced it's _faster._

Comment: You could write that as: `for item in some_func() or []: pass` or
 `[do_something(item) for item in some_func() or []]`.

Comment: Also consider the case when you need to do something different when the function returns no results, you would have to first check the iterator's size.

Comment: @espeed: Well, I didn't say you can't return None. I just say that you usually should return empty iter just for interface ease, in my opinion it's more pythonic then returning None. None should be returned in case something gone wrong. In example I return None when my method in tcp server `parse_data(buffer)` couldn't parse for whatever reason. I can't raise exception because it's async server, and I have to know that sent data was malicious so I return None.

Comment: @MattBall: speed will depend on type of data returned. I just assumed that most of the time iter object would be returned and then additional `if` will be slower for sure. But if most of the time None is going to be returned then probably checking `is None` is faster then initializing iterator over empty iter. We would have to make some tests anyway.

Comment: unless you are initializing `[]` as a default argument in a function, in which case `None` is usually preferred.

Answer (score 5):

A general practice that I've been taught to follow is to return the same data type for all valid values within the input domain, if you can. It makes it easier for others to use your code, and your documentation will be cleaner. For values that are outside of the valid input domain, raise Exceptions.

An empty iterator, rather than None, seems to be a better practice in this case. I know other programming languages like to return null in these instances, but I don't see a benefit to doing that in the scenario you described.

Comment: One of the reasons I have been in the "don't return an empty iterator" camp is because if you need to do something for the empty case, you'll have to check the iterator's size via `if len(results):` and this could be expensive if the iterator is large, whereas `if results is None:` is cheap and thus more flexible.

Comment: if x is an iterator, "if x" will return False if the x is empty

Comment: @AshwinBalamohan No it won't. `bool(iter(()))` evaluates to `True`. In general you don't know if an iterable is empty unless you start to iterate through it. Not unless it is has a __len__() method like a list or a tuple.